# there is problem in importing my class in scrapy spider

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I am facing problem since one week .I was not able to import my class in the scrapy spider(in shareprice.py).I have tried many ways but not found anywhere please give me the solution .
shareprice.py and my class in the same directory in spiders

```
import scrapy
import json
import sys
from .myclass import *
```

The error I get is:

> error -attempted relative import with no known parent package

Answer (score 0):

To make a directory a real python package place an empty `__init__.py` file in it.
Also `import *` something is bad practice most of the time. You should only import functions and classes you really need (explicit is better than implicit).